# How to destroy a record using a form in Laravel and display status?

Tags: laravel, forms, http, model-view-controller

I'm using Laravel and I am currently implementing the 'destroy' method in a resource controller as part of CRUD. The method should delete the specified record in my database.

The method is called by my blade.php file, which uses a form with the DELETE method and `route('my-resources.destroy', $my-resource->id)`. I want the controller to return a string such as 'Deleted successfully!' so that I can display that to the client.

Here is my code:

In views/book/edit.blade.php:

```
<form method="DELETE" action="{{ route('books.destroy', $book->id) }}">
    <div class="form-item center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and in BookController.php:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $book = Book::find($id);
        $book->delete();

        return redirect()->away('https://www.google.com');
    }
```

I put a redirect to google.com just to see if the redirect works, but it doesn't. When I click the 'Delete' button, the url changes from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/1/edit` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/books/1?` with that question mark at the end. What am I doing wrong?

I have another question: if I want to return the status, should I use something like

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Deleted successfully';
});
```

or

```
$request->session()->flash('status', 'Task was successful!');
/** and some random return statement **/
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forms do not support the `DELETE` method so you need to use the Laravel `@method` helper to tell Laravel you want to use the `DELETE` verb. Additionally, you need to include the `csrf` token that Laravel expects are part of preventing cross-site request forgeries.

```
<form action="{{ route('books.destroy', $book->id) }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  @method("DELETE")
  ... // Button/link for submit this form
</form>
```

You may need to define your `route` so that it accepts a `DELETE` request, unless you have defined a `resourceful` route:

```
Route::delete('/books/{id}', 'BookController@destroy')
  ->name('books.destroy'); // Laravel 7
Route::delete('/books/{id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\BookController::class, 'destroy'])
  ->name('books.destroy'); // Laravel 8
```

If you're using `resourceful` routes, they will be made available for you already:

```
Route::resource('/books', 'BookController'); // Laravel 7
Route::resource('/books', \App\Controllers\Http\BookController::class); // Laravel 8
```

For your `destroy` method, set a `flash` message to be sent back:

```
public function destroy(Book $id)
{
  $id->delete();

  return redirect('/')->with('success', 'Book deleted');
}
```

Then flash the message in your view:

```
@if (session('success'))
  <p>{{ session('success') }}</p>
@endif
```

Comment: Since it's a resource route I assume, we will not need to additionally add the route in web.php file.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi A valid point. Updated my answer to make that more obvious.